# How to most easily duplicate a piece of text in Vim?

Tags: vim

Let's say I have a piece of text within my code which I want duplicated.

What I've been doing so far is to move to the start, press `v` to enter visual mode, then move to the end, press `y` to yank the text, move one character back and then `p` to put it there.

Is there an easier way? Something like:

1. Select text with `v`.
2. Press some sequence of commands and there is - it's duplicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's the "move one char back" you're trying to avoid, press `P` rather than `p` for the "paste" operation.

Comment: Now that you said it, yes that was *the* annoying part. Tried it out - it was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can always define custom macros / shortcuts on the fly.

```
map ! "+yP
```

will allow you to enter visual with `v`, mark the text, and use `!` to duplicate it once (for extra duplicates, repeat `p` or `P` as needed.